# Hibernate/JPA, field 'accreditation_company_id' doesn't have a default value error

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I faced the issue described in the title saving my entity though everything in code and db tables seems ok.
Here is my code:

```
@Entity  
public class Company {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "company_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    List<CompanyObject> companyObjects;
}  


@Entity
public class CompanyObject {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Long id;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    ObjectType type;
}
```

Here is my table definitions:

```
CREATE TABLE `company` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=32 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `company_object` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `company_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK__company` (`company_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK__company` FOREIGN KEY (`company_id`) REFERENCES `company` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Object I'm trying to save contains the following info:

Company(id=32, companyObjects=[CompanyObject(id=null, type=NEW)])

Here is the code I use to save the object:

Controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/company/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String editCompany(@PathVariable("id") long companyId,
                          @ModelAttribute("form") CompanyDto form) {
    Company company = companyService.getCompanyById(companyId);
    companyService.updateCompany(company, form);
    return "redirect:/companies";
}
```

Service method:

```
@Transactional
    public Company updateCompany(Company company, final CompanyDto form) {
        company.getCompanyObjects().clear();
        company.getCompanyObjects().addAll(form.getCompanyObjects());
        return companyRepository.save(company);
    }
```

Am I getting this right that hibernate automatically generate and populate all the missing ids in these objects? If yes what am I missing and why the error appears?

Comment: How are you saving these objects? Show us some code.

Comment: @nagyf, I update answer with some code. Thanks for comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some problems here. Firstly, your table definitions are wrong, check your `accreditation_object` table, you have a foreign key there which references a column that doesn't exist: `company_id` should be `accreditation_company_id`.
(or is it just some copy-paste error?)

Secondly, your entities are wrong, try this way:

```
@Entity  
public class Company {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="company", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    Set<CompanyObject> companyObjects;
}  


@Entity
public class CompanyObject {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Long id;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    ObjectType type;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "company_id")
    Company company;
}
```

Note the `@ManyToOne` annotation in the CompanyObject. If I understand correctly, you want to assign one or more CompanyObject to a Company, thus you have to have a `@ManyToOne` annotated `Company` typed field in the `CompanyObject`.

Now, if you want to save these objects, first save the `Company` instance, then iterate over the list of `CompanyObject`s, set the previously saved company instance, and then save the `CompanyObject`s, something like this:

```
Company company = new Company();
companyDao.persist(company);

List<CompanyObject> companyObjects = new ArrayList<>();
// populate the list somehow
// ...

for(CompanyObject obj: companyObjects){
    obj.setCompany(company);
    companyObjectDao.persist(obj);
}
```

Your updateCompany method is wrong, you should try something like the above code. (I cannot rewrite your example because it looks like something is missing there. What is CompanyDTO?)

**Edit:** You can use cascade saving (note: I've updated the `Company` entity), just be sure to set the `Company` instance to every `CompanyObject` instance, like:

```
@Transactional
public Company updateCompany(Company company, final CompanyDto form) {
    company.getCompanyObjects().clear();
    company.getCompanyObjects().addAll(form.getCompanyObjects());
    for(CompanyObject obj : company.getCompanyObjects()){
       obj.setCompany(company);
    }
    return companyRepository.save(company);
}
```

I think this should work, but I'm not a 100% sure. Give it a try.

Comment: Thanks a million @nagyf, I'll give it a try. Regarding a mess with the naming - you're right, this is just a copy-paste mistake. Just wondering if it is possible to leave object structure I have and perform saving somehow? Isn't `cascade` property is designed for child save, is it?

Comment: No probs, I'm glad I could help ;)